# React JS: Pass event inside onChange drop down (Ant Design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a drop down in my form (https://ant.design/components/select). In this select drop down I have the onChange to call a function. Inside 'onChange' I want to pass the event as a parameter to my function. The problem is: when the onChange occurs, only the selected value is passed, but I want the entire event.

**Here is the code:**

```
export default class MyForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event); // here I'm receiving only the value selected (1 or 2)
    }

    render() {
        render(
           <Form>
              <Select onChange={this.handleOnChange}>

                      <Option value="1">text 1</Option>
                      <Option value="2">text 2</Option>
              </Select>
           </Form>
        )
    }
}
```

In the console.log() I'm receiving only the selected value. Is there a way to pass the entire event object to the function handleOnChange()?

Comment: This depends entirely on how the `<Select>` component is implemented, as it is the caller of the handler function.

Comment: what's in your `<Select>`? Otherwise it's working sa expected -  https://codesandbox.io/s/4xPyO7zwk

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution. Just use: onSelect(), passing the value and the event.

```
handleOnChange = (value, event) => {
        ...code here        
}

    render() {
        render(
           <Form>
              <Select onSelect={(value, event) => this.handleOnChange(value, event)}>

                      <Option value="1">text 1</Option>
                      <Option value="2">text 2</Option>
              </Select>
           </Form>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Is there demo where i will be able to see this. Cause when i try to use this in a select getting error that instance.render is not a function.

Comment: It passes option as a second arg. I wanted to stop propagation. How exactly is this accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `Select` component that you use is the one that handle the `onChange` and call your "outer" function.

What you can try is use the synthetic event variable inside your function, it might work:

```
handleOnChange = (selectedValue) => {
    console.log(selectedValue); // The value from the inner component
    console.log(event); // usually you have access to this variable
}
```

Comment: how can i stop propagation using event which i get?

Comment: Depends on the component you use/native javascript - provide some code example.

Comment: i am using ANT Select Component inside dropdown on selecting value from select closes dropdown which has prop handleVisibleChange. I think its because of bubbling of event

Comment: Without looking at example it's really hard to understand

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404943/ant-select-closes-dropdown

Answer (score -3):

Try this, if you dont want to bind in callback in Select onSelect/onChange:

```
toggleActive = name => event => {
  console.log("name: ",name) // prints "name: Active!"
  console.log("event: ",event) // event is some data
}

<Select
 mode="multiple"
 style={{ width: '91%' }}
 placeholder="Stuff"
 value={this.props.value}
 onChange={this.toggleActive("Active!")}
>
```