# Ant Select closes dropdown

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, antd

I am using Ant Select component inside Dropdown component. Here is my index file which renders Dropdown

```
const getMenu = filter => (
  <MenuContainer
    ...
  />
);

<Dropdown
  overlay={getMenu(searchFilter)}
  trigger={['click']}
  visible={this.state.search}
  onVisibleChange={val =>
    this.handleDropdownVisibility(val, searchFilter)
  }
>
  ...
</Dropdown>
```

Here is my MenuContainer which return Select Component inside it

```
handleSelectChange = val => {
  this.setState({
    selectedValue: val,
  });
};

<Select
   ref="selectBox"
   onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
   style={{ width: '100%' }}
>
  {numberComparision.map((item, i) => {
    return (
     <Option key={i} value={item.id}>
      {item.name}
     </Option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```

so on clicking select value onVisibleChange fires and closes dropdown
[image: Select box inside dropdown]

Comment: This is not a working example. Please provide a jsfiddle/codepen/something that we can debug.

Comment: @Dekel here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/Atif86/pen/mxmGzy on clicking value from select box dropdown fires onVisibleChange and dropdown gets closed

Comment: Related - [Github Ant issue thread](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12420)

Answer (score 1):

In current v3.3.1 there is no API to prevent to close the `Dropdown` list.

As a solution I can offer **[this custom component](https://codesandbox.io/s/71ll81l72q)**.

[image]

`Item` has a property `clickable` which indicates will be the droplist closed after click or not. You can set `true/false` or css name of an element which should not trigger closing drop-list.

Answer (score 1):

Change Menu.Item where the select is contained to a Menu.ItemGroup, those do not trigger the onVisibleChange when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing components that are not meant to be mixed here, I believe.

Dropdown expects its overlay to be a menu of some sorts. Or at least something static that does not open yet another dynamic `<div>` layer.

Select already has a dropdown type behaviour. So your Dropdown opens the Select which opens the Select dropdown, and then they both react to  the click event and close.

It is currently not clear from your question and screenshot what you are actually trying to achieve, that could not be achieved using just a Select. You could try clarifying that.