# Typescript conversion error for select event and default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, react-hooks

TSlint throws an error on defaulValue - `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | undefined` -  for following code

```
const App = () => {
  const [ month, setMonth] = useState("last1")
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      console.log(e);
      setMonth(e.target.value);
  }
  ...
```

and then inside return

```
  <Select defaultValue={month} style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` component that you use would most probably be passing the value to the `onChange handler` instead of the event and hence you get that warning

You should instead define it like

```
const App = () => {
  const [ month, setMonth] = useState("last1")
  const handleChange = (value: string) => {
      setMonth(value);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Yeah it does pass string as first arg and option as second. Was reading on same from https://ant.design/components/select/ docs. I just wanted stop propagation for same. I'll be doomed if they're not providing basic event handler

Comment: Feeling foolish to ask this question now. I assumed almost they must be providing the same and thought it as typescript ( new to it ) error

Comment: @kushalvm here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393999/react-select-cant-stoppropagation-on-valuerenderer-component

Comment: @ma_dev_15 M not using react-select but ant design as a UI library

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684925/react-js-pass-event-inside-onchange-drop-down-ant-design @kushalvm

Comment: AntD uses rc-select component, and probably they might already be stopping propagation. I will search and let you know if I find anything. Check this code https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/master/src/Select.tsx

Comment: Ummm...I actually passed select component inside header prop of Collapse component as React node. Not sure if the context helps but just mentioned. Pretty sure it doesn't prevents that